# Application .dot templates for PPA and Non-Provisionals Patents

Tags: application

Ideally, there would be a .dot files (for provisional / non-provisional patent applications) that would take care of [formatting details per the USPTO spec](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-getting-started/patent-basics/types-patent-applications/nonprovisional-utility-patent#heading-4).  In addition would be helpful if the .dot template included the outline for the document: prompting inventors with specific questions to advance a draft as far as possible so that it can be handed off to a patent attorney or agent.   A superior .dot would incorporate advance word-processing features such as auto-numbering of paragraphs and references.

I am interested in understanding:

1. Is there a USPTO preferred ['style' in the MS-Word sense](https://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/stylesms.html) for patent applications?
2. Are there good .dot templates (provisional / non provisional) templates that meet the description above?

Links to good .doc patent application or .dot template is appreciated.

Comment: After you set centered page numbers, font 12 and 1.5 line spacing, there is a large amount of substantive work ahead.  Paragraph numbering can be a little tricky but line numbers are very easy to set. Any line/paragraph numbering is optional. Do start the Claims and Abstract on a new page.